# How do I output an attribute of multiple instances of a resource created with for_each?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+

Let's say I have a map of environments to supply to for_each

```
environments = {
    "0" = "dev"
    "1" = "test"
    "2" = "stage"
}
```

Then for whatever reason I want to create an Azure Resource Group for each environment.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  for_each = var.environments
  name     = "${var.resource-group-name}-${each.value}-rg"
  location = var.location
}
```

How do I get the outputs? I've tried the new splat to no avail.

```
output "name" {
  value = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group[*].name}"
}

output "id" {
  value = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group[*].id}"
}

output "location" {
  value = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group[*].location}"
}
```

Error: Unsupported attribute

```
in output "id":
   6:   value = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group[*].id}"

This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

How do I output an attribute of multiple instances of a resource created with for_each?

Comment: Why is this a map instead of just a list/set if you aren't actually using the keys?

Comment: Given the config provided, `environments` could be a List instead of a Map type, and the location output could be `value = var.location`. Besides that, the `azurerm_resource_group.resource_group` object will not support the splat operator as you have discovered yourself. That was the version < 0.12 workaround for outputs, but does not translate to the new iterators unfortunately. I am not sure if what you are trying to do is currently possible.

Comment: I have to use a Map because it's what for_each requires. I am basically just trying to get the output of each element as you use to do with count and splat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[*]` is a shorthand for extracting attributes from a list of objects. `for_each` makes a resource appear as a *map* of objects instead, so the `[*]` operator is not appropriate.

However, [`for` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions) are a more general mechanism that can turn either a list or a map into another list or map by evaluating an arbitrary expression for each element of the source collection.

Therefore we can simplify a map of `azurerm_resource_group` objects into a map of *names* of those objects like this:

```
output "name" {
  value = { for k, group in azurerm_resource_group.resource_group: k => group.name }
}
```

Your input map uses numeric indexes as keys, which is unusual but allowed. Because of that, the resulting value for the output would be something like this:

```
{
  "0" = "something-dev-rg"
  "1" = "something-test-rg"
  "2" = "something-stage-rg"
}
```

It's more common for a map in `for_each` to include a meaningful name as the key, so that the resulting instances are identified by that meaningful name rather than by incrementing integers. If you changed your configuration to use the environment name as the key instead, the map of names would look like this instead:

```
{
  "dev"   = "something-dev-rg"
  "test"  = "something-test-rg"
  "stage" = "something-stage-rg"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** for_each doesn't work with output

```
output "name"{
  value = { for k, v in var.environments : v => azurerm_resource_group.resource_group[k].name }
}

output "id"{
  value = { for k, v in var.environments : v => azurerm_resource_group.resource_group[k].id }
}

output "location"{
  value = { for k, v in var.environments : v => azurerm_resource_group.resource_group[k].location }
}
```

Example output,

```
id = {
  "dev" = "xxx"
  "stage" = "yyy"
  "test" = "zzz"
}
```

Comment: ```in output "name":
   2:   for_each = var.environments

An argument named "for_each" is not expected here.
```